# Replace ideographic fullstop with CJK package

Tags: cjk, catcodes

A common method to replace the ideographic fullstop (`。`) with fullwidth fullstop (`．`) is to change the catcode:

```
\catcode`\。 = \active
\let。=．
```

However, this method will break when using `CJK` package with pdfLaTeX since this package has already made `。` to be a macro. So how to achieve this effect with `CJK`?

PS: I use UTF8 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a [similar question](http://bbs.ctex.org/forum.php?mod=viewthread&tid=71625) but for GBK encoding (in Chinese). Here is the solution:

```
% For GBK
% Put it after \begin{document}
\let\oldaone^^a1
\def^^a1#1{\ifnum`#1=`^^a3\relax ^^a3^^ae\else \oldaone #1\fi}
```

I have modified it for UTF8:

```
% For UTF8
% Put it after \begin{document}
\makeatletter
\let\old@e@iii=^^e3
\def^^e3^^80#1{%
  \ifnum`#1=`^^82\relax
    ^^ef^^bc^^8e%
  \else
    \old@e@iii ^^80#1%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

Things like `^^xx` are actually how the characters are represented under certain encodings: `^^e3^^80^^82` is "。" and `^^ef^^bc^^8e` is "．" in UTF8.